# wald.test: Error in L %*% V : non-conformable arguments

Tags: r

When I attempt to run `wald.test` (from the `aod` package) on a categorical variable on my linear model, I get the following error:

```
Error in L %*% V : non-conformable arguments
```

The code that I'm having trouble with:

```
m1 <- glm(comment_count ~ factor(has_conflicts) + factor(base_repo_id) + **snip**, data = mydata)
summary(m1) # shows that base_repo_id's factors are coefficients 3 through 12

# Determine whether base_repo_id matters
wald.test(b = coef(m1), Sigma = vcov(m1), Terms = 3:12)
```

As I understand it, `wald.test`'s `b` parameter is the linear regression's coefficients, `Sigma` is the regression's variances, and `Terms` selects the variables I want to run the Wald test on. So why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 1):

In principle your code looks ok but it must be something about the particular fit to your data that did not work. Maybe there have been problems with non-identified parameters or a singular covariance matrix or something like that?

If I create a random data set with the variables above, then everything runs smoothly:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(
  comment_count = rpois(500, 3),
  has_conflicts = sample(0:1, 500, replace = TRUE),
  base_repo_id = sample(1:11, 500, replace = TRUE)
)    
m1 <- glm(comment_count ~ factor(has_conflicts) + factor(base_repo_id),
  data = mydata)
```

The Wald test can then be carried out by base R's anova() (which in the Gaussian case is equivalent to the Wald test):

```
m0 <- update(m1, . ~. - factor(base_repo_id))
anova(m0, m1, test = "Chisq")
## Analysis of Deviance Table
## 
## Model 1: comment_count ~ factor(has_conflicts)
## Model 2: comment_count ~ factor(has_conflicts) + factor(base_repo_id)
##   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
## 1       498     1426.1                     
## 2       488     1389.2 10    36.91   0.2256
```

Or you can use `aod`:

```
library("aod")
wald.test(b = coef(m1), Sigma = vcov(m1), Terms = 3:12)               
## Wald test:
## ----------
## 
## Chi-squared test:
## X2 = 13.0, df = 10, P(> X2) = 0.23
```

Or `lmtest`:

```
library("lmtest")
waldtest(m1, "factor(base_repo_id)", test = "Chisq")     
## Wald test
## 
## Model 1: comment_count ~ factor(has_conflicts) + factor(base_repo_id)
## Model 2: comment_count ~ factor(has_conflicts)
##   Res.Df  Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
## 1    488                      
## 2    498 -10 12.966     0.2256
```

Or `car`:

```
library("car")
linearHypothesis(m1, names(coef(m1))[3:12])
## Linear hypothesis test
## 
## Hypothesis:
## factor(base_repo_id)2 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)3 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)4 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)5 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)6 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)7 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)8 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)9 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)10 = 0
## factor(base_repo_id)11 = 0
## 
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: comment_count ~ factor(has_conflicts) + factor(base_repo_id)
## 
##   Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
## 1    498                     
## 2    488 10 12.966     0.2256
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem.
The error shows that the size of two matrix L and V does not match.

Please check whether there are NA elements in your coefficients.
vcov() removes NA elements automatically which changes the size of the matrix so that their sizes do not match.